# Using several production lines to parallely process multiple tasks from one queue in JavaFX

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, parallel-processing

I have a queue of tasks

```
Queue<Task> tasks = new LinkedList<>();
```

I have three production lines that can accept Task and work on it. I would like these three production lines to work parallelly each on one task until they finish all tasks in the queue.

My current implementation of Three production lines is with Execution Service with fixed amount of Three threads

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
```

Different production lines implement a callable interface. Each call method processes one task, which means it contacts synchronized warehouses for materials, updates the gui to show a task is being worked on...

However, I don't know how to implement the logic of giving task after task to a different production line. There is no order to different production lines, I just want them to work all the time on doing different tasks and after one of the lines finishes working on given tasks it takes next one from the queue.

```
 ProductionLineA productionLine1 = new ProductionLineA(tasks, this,
                        localWarehouse, distantWarehouse);
 ProductionLineB productionLine2 = new ProductionLineB(tasks, this,
                        localWarehouse, distantWarehouse);
 ProductionLineC productionLine3 = new ProductionLineC(tasks, this,
                        localWarehouse, distantWarehouse);
 pool.submit(productionLine1);
 pool.submit(productionLine2);
 pool.submit(productionLine3);
```

Update

In the beginning,  users chooses some specific tasks, it looks like this[image] and hit starts, at that moment I want my three production lines to start working on this queue of tasks the way I mentioned before. Those tasks aren't of type runnable, they are basically the same thing just with differences of calculating required materials to produce them. That is the reason why I had them inside a constructor of different product lines.

Comment: Doesn't the `ExecutorService` already implement that logic? Just submit all the tasks to the pool, and the behavior you want is exactly what will happen. https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int)

Comment: Sure but I don't know how to submit those tasks from the queue because you have three different production lines

Comment: You don't need your queue; the executor already implements a queue. Just submit all the tasks directly to the pool, as you do in the last code block. You can submit more than three, and they will wait for an available thread.

Comment: see answers to similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61945308/processing-tasks-in-parallel-and-sequentially-java/61953721#61953721

Comment: @James_D Sorry but I still don't understand. Does those tasks I'm submitting have to implement interface task ? Currently they are of my own type. When I do submit tasks it throws wrong type error.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you're trying to do, but yes, they would have to implement `Runnable` or `Callable`. You can always just wrap the call to whatever method you want to run in a runnable, e.g. `pool.submit(() -> productionLine1.runProductionLine());` or just `pool.submit(productionLine1::runProductionLine);`. However, to interact with JavaFX, it might be more convenient to submit a `Task` subclass.

Comment: @James_D But I need that queue, it's the starting point of my application.

Comment: Then I probably don't fully understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: How can the queue be the starting point of the application, if it depends on choices the user makes via gui? Since I don't understand what you're trying to achieve, my answer {here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61065745/2991525) may or may not be helpful; it simulates running a multiple sets of tasks one after another using an executor service...

Comment: @fabian Users first choose tasks he wants to start and presses start, the user cannot do anything and the queue is populated(it's being populated while he clicks on the plus buttons on the picture above, after clicking on the start he can't do anything anymore). After that, I submit my production lines with that queue of tasks to the pool to work on it the way I described.